# Mesons as a two-body problem is semiclassical QCD?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, semiclassical, mesons

In particle physics and quantum field theory, mesons are interpreted as a system composed of a quark and an anti-quark, and the color charge of both must be at each opposite moment (green/anti-green, red/anti-red, etc.).

Quantum details are immensely complicated and only recently has QCD lattice allowed us to obtain numerical results on the mass and other properties of such quantum systems called mesons.
However, I wonder to what extent the semiclassical behavior of such systems can be directly calculated. That is, assuming that a specific semiclassical meson is permanently formed by a quark of a certain type and an antiquark (think for example of a meson $\pi^+ = u\bar{d}$). In principle we could use the Lagrangian of QCD:

$$\mathcal{L}_\mathrm{QCD} = \bar{\psi}_i  \left( i \gamma^\mu (D_\mu)_{ij} - m\, \delta_{ij}\right) \psi_j - \frac{1}{4}G^a_{\mu \nu} G^{\mu \nu}_a $$

Where $a\in\{1,\dots,8\}$ is the color-index, $\left( D_\mu \right)_{ij} = \partial_\mu \delta_{ij} - i g \left( T_a \right)_{ij} A^a_\mu \,$ a differential operator involving color-indexs $i,j$ and space-time-indexs $\mu$.

To see what theoretical properties (very different from real quantum properties) would have the meson $\pi^+$. Specifically, I wonder:

1. What would be the Euler-Lagrange equations of such a system? Or at least, how many of these equations would it have given the number of complex functions that describe the two quarks and the gluon vector potentials $A^a_\mu$?
2. What can we classically extract from these equations? How would the problem change if we described the system as two point-quarks moving around a center of mass and calculated a linear approximation to the equations of motion?

**My personal attempt**: To begin with each of the two quarks is described by a bi-spinor (four complex functions), so apparently we have 8 related unknown functions for which we should pose 8 partial differential equations. The interaction of gluons requires an additional number of complex functions to describe the gluon field. So, a huge system of nonlinear partial differential equations appears (I don't even have an idea how to write them intelligently using the minimum number of components).

Comment: The closest people have gotten to your spirit is with $b\bar b$ mesons, involving color binding of ***heavy*** quarks at energies above the chiral-symmetry breaking scale. For light  hadrons, the binding of *constituent* quarks  is best approximated in chiral-bag effective models, in a weird region sandwiched between the chiral symmetry breaking and confinement scales... Paradoxically, it entails Goldstone pions ***and*** massive constituent quarks in the same breath (!!) which is why real pions simply cannot be thought of as bound states of constituent quarks.   Obviates your framework...